# One Citroen C4 remote doesn't work after driving (but the other does)

Tags: citroen, fob, citroen-c4

I own a 2010 C4 Grand Picasso. I have two key fobs, one of which is doing strange things.

I can open, lock, turn lights on etc, but after driving the car and getting out the remote fails to work at all.

If I then use the other key fob to open or lock, then the faulty one starts working again until I go for a drive!!

I doubt it's the battery as it works fine after I use the other key and then use it again.

Any ideas what might be causing this or how I can fix it?

Answer (score 2):

You can always try and change the battery, even if it appears to work at times.

It is probably the only facet of a fob key that we humans without programming devices can control

Comment: Considering the cost of a battery, I agree it's a great place to start.